# How to translate 超然物外?

Tags: meaning

I was looking up the saying:

登东山而小鲁，登泰山而小天下。

Part of the [explanation](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%99%BB%E6%B3%B0%E5%B1%B1%E8%80%8C%E5%B0%8F%E5%A4%A9%E4%B8%8B/2043905) says:

用超然物外的心境来观看世间的变幻纷扰。

Can someone please expand 超然物外?

Maybe: 超过自然，物质外边 ？？

Comment: bkrs：超然物外[be free from things of the world; hold aloof from the world] 超出现实生活之外

1) 超出於尘世之外。
2) 引申为置身事外的意思。
 **超然**  (1) [detached]∶超脱世俗
历史家所必需的超然态度 （1) detached; independent
这位超然的作曲家对舆论既不担心，也不在意。 The aloof composer neither worried nor cared about public opinion.
 **物外** 〈书〉世事之外：超然物外[aloof from worldly things] 世外; 世俗之外
飘然物外1) 事物本体以外。2) 逸尘脱俗的世界。1) p.w. the realm beyond worldly things
2) attr. transcendental

Comment: **超**  ［动］（越过; 高出） exceed; surpass; overtake:（在某个范围以外; 不受限制） transcend; go beyond:
超尘脱俗 transcend the worldly ［形］
（超出寻常的） super-; ultra-; extra-; hyper-
 **然**  (most common) adverbial suffix, cf.(Yip Po-Ching, CLCS) calmness：寂然、安然、泰然、坦然，clarity：了然、显然、斐然、照然，solemnity:赫然、昂然、凛然、俨然

Answer (score 1):

**ABC**

> hold aloof from the world

**A Chinese-English Dictionary**

> hold oneself aloof from the world; be above worldly considerations; stay away from scenes of contention

**Oxford**

> 1 置身事外 be above worldly considerations
>
> 2 超脱于社会 shun social disputes

**KEY**

> 1 be above all material desires
>
> 2 be detached
>
> 3 be above the fray

**Duogongneng Chengyu Cidian**

> **解释** 超然:不站在对立各方的任何一方;物:指客观世界｡超脱于尘事之外｡也指置身事外｡
>
> **语见** 宋·叶梦得《石林诗话》卷下:“渊明正以脱略世故､超然物外意,顾区区在位者何足累其心哉!"
>
> **例句** 这一种仪式既经举行,即倘有后患,各部都该负责,不能超然物外,说风凉话了｡(鲁迅《而已集·谈所谓“大内档案"》)
>
> **近义** 置身事外
>
> **反义** 同流合污
>
> **辨析**〔参见〕置身事外

- 超然 is just "independent"
- 物 is the "objective world"
- 外 is "outside of"

Comment: 超然物外的心境 ‘with a detached mind' 好不好？

Comment: with a detached mind from worldly pursuits?

Answer (score 1):

超然 = Go beyond

物外 = outside of Material world

超然物外 = Go beyond the mundane world = **Spiritual** (not necessary  religious)